# In jQuery, $('body') can be selecting the body element, but $('body') can be just like $('some text'), so how to distinguish?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The reason is that we can do

```
$('<div>some text</div>').prependTo('#someDiv')
```

so, this is also ok to do:

```
$('some text').prependTo('#someDiv')
```

but we can't change `some text` to `body`?  `body` is just as good as any text...

(the above code is adding `some text` to the div with id `someDiv`, so what if I want to add the word `body` to the div?)

but $('body') becomes a selector for the body element... so is there a rule that says, we can use any text as HTML code, so long as it is not the name of HTML elements?

Comment: could you elaborate a little more please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically this is never valid:

```
$('generic text here, *not* a selector or HTML');
```

That should *always* be either a selector (finding an element) or html (creating element(s)), [you can view the API for `$()` here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

You want to use one of the other [DOM Insertion methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) here, [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) in this case:

```
$('#someDiv').prepend('any text or html here is valid, <b>Hey look bold</b>.');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it contains html tags then it is treated as html (except it strips text before the first tag and after the last). eg `$("<div>some text</div>")`. Otherwise it is treated as a selector, eg `$("some text")`.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with text nodes isn't JQuery's strong suit. You could use normal DOM methods:

```
$('#someDiv')[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode("body"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because jQuery considers selectors before creating HTML snippets. "body" is a valid selector and will be used as a selector.

You'd be better of using the prepend function to prepend HTML or text to a node:

```
 $('#someDiv').prepend('some text');
```

The value passed to prepend is not used a selector and you could add the text "body".